# Edit : javafx : Exception Councurrent Modification How to Handle it

Tags: java, javafx

i have ListView I want to maintain state of check box . i collect all task checked in list view and after update listview(add new element to list it goes refresh/reload so i remove all value from GUI which is selected with task keys and try to add again same with new object by set manually value of check box task to true....it gives me following exception so how to handle it...
Exception public void run method where i try to remove value from main box according to key value 
I paste method which i call and line no where i got exception.

```
public synchronized static void getCollectVCF() {
        testVCF = false;
        if (geneBowserFlag == false) {
            checklist.setDisable(true);
        } else {
            checklist.setDisable(false);
        }

        taskNames = LoadVCFFileToTrack.tempVcfList.toArray(new String[LoadVCFFileToTrack.tempVcfList.size()]);
        reactionStrings = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HBox>();
        if (LoadVCFFileToTrack.tempVcfList.size() > 0) {
            int count = 0;
            for (String s : taskNames) {
                if (LoadVCFFileToTrack.flagBrowse == false || LoadVCFFileToTrack.CollectedPath != null) {
                    if (count <= taskNames.length) {
                        for (String s1 : LoadVCFFileToTrack.CollectedPath) {
                            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substringAfterLast(s1, "/"))) {
                                ReadVCFFile.tableGenrate(s1);
                                reactionStrings.put(s, GetSequences.call(LoadGenomeSequence.start,
                                        LoadGenomeSequence.end, ReadVCFFile.collectMultipleObj));
                                System.out.println(
                                        "value : " + s + "\tCountSize  : " + ReadVCFFile.collectMultipleObj.size());
                                VCFTableObj.put(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substringAfterLast(s1, "/"),
                                        ReadVCFFile.collectMultipleObj);
                                count++;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    for (String s1 : TrackFile.listOFVCF) {
                        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substringAfterLast(s1, "/"))) {
                            ReadVCFFile.tableGenrate(s1);
                            reactionStrings.put(s, GetSequences.call(LoadGenomeSequence.start, LoadGenomeSequence.end,
                                    ReadVCFFile.collectMultipleObj));
                            System.out.println("value list of File: " + s + "\tCountSize  : "
                                    + ReadVCFFile.collectMultipleObj.size());
                            VCFTableObj.put(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substringAfterLast(s1, "/"),
                                    ReadVCFFile.collectMultipleObj);
                            count++;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        reactionStringsvcf = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HBox>();
        {
            for (String s : taskNames) {
                reactionStringsvcf.put(s, GetSequences.TitleBox(s));
            }
        }

        tasks2 = FXCollections
                .observableArrayList(Arrays.stream(taskNames).map(Task::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        for (Entry<String, HBox> entry : checkSelectedValuesVCF.entrySet()) {
            for (Task t : tasks2) {
                String s = t.name.toString();
                s = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringAfterLast(s, ":");
                s = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(s, "]");

                if (entry.getKey().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(s.trim())) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            GenerateDraggableGUI.mainbox.getChildren().remove(entry.getValue());
                            CollectedSeq.remove(entry.getKey());
                            t.setSelected(true);
                            testVCF = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        synchronized (TitledPanes.class) {

            tasks2.forEach(task -> task.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
                VCFMapLocal = new LinkedHashMap<String, HBox>();
                if (isSelected) {
                    GenerateDraggableGUI.mainbox.getChildren().add(reactionStringsvcf.get(task.getName()));
                    VCFMap.put(reactionStringsvcf.get(task.getName()), reactionStrings.get(task.getName()));
                    VCFMapLocal.put((task.getName()), reactionStrings.get(task.getName()));
                    checkSelectedValuesVCF.put(task.getName(), reactionStringsvcf.get(task.getName()));
                    SetOfAll.put(reactionStringsvcf.get(task.getName()), reactionStrings.get(task.getName()));
                    CollectedSeq.add(task.getName());
                    GenerateDraggableGUI.LoadGUIVCF();
                }
                if (wasSelected) {
                    GenerateDraggableGUI.mainbox.getChildren().remove(reactionStringsvcf.get(task.getName()));
                    GenerateDraggableGUI.mainContent.getChildren().remove(reactionStrings.get(task.getName()));
                    VCFMap.remove(reactionStringsvcf.get(task.getName()), reactionStrings.get(task.getName()));
                    SetOfAll.remove(reactionStringsvcf.get(task.getName()), reactionStrings.get(task.getName()));
                    checkSelectedValuesVCF.remove(task.getName());
                    CollectedSeq.remove(task.getName());
                    GenerateDraggableGUI.UnLoadGUI();
                }
            }));
        }
```

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.WeakHashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(WeakHashMap.java:806)
    at java.util.WeakHashMap$EntryIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:845)
    at java.util.WeakHashMap$EntryIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:843)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.forget(StyleManager.java:520)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.scenesChanged(Parent.java:652)
    at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:832)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:898)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.scenesChanged(Parent.java:656)
    at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:832)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:898)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.scenesChanged(Parent.java:656)
    at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:832)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:898)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.scenesChanged(Parent.java:656)
    at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:832)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:898)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:495)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:221)
    at org.ArrayGen.FXFeatures.TitledPanes$4.run(TitledPanes.java:418)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$67/1869691259.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$65/22805895.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$52/1429880200.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception occurs when you try to modify a `Collection` while iterating through its elements. To avoid this, you can use the iterator of the collection (`Collection#iterator()`) to traverse through the elements, then you can invoke `iterator#remove()` to remove the currently active item.

Useful Link :

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html